# Use SQL keyword as alias name of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alias, keyword

I'm executing the following query but it is giving syntax error. Because the keyword `key` is registered in SQL

```
SELECT `id` AS key, `country_name` AS value FROM countries
```

I also tried using brackets like this but it's not working:

```
SELECT `id` AS [key], `country_name` AS value FROM countries
```

How to deal with it?

Comment: use also backtick on the alias `\`key\``. using `[ ]` works in SQL Server.

Comment: MySQL you have to use the `key` symbol. In MSSQL Server you need to use [key] so MySQL: SELECT `id` AS `key`, `country_name` AS value FROM countries. and then in MSSQL Server SELECT [id] AS [key], [country_name] AS value FROM countries

Comment: But technically you don't need the [] around the column name unless the column name has spaces in it or the key has spaces in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **backtick(`)** or **Single Quote(')** to give alias name of column in MySQL.

Try this:

```
SELECT `id` AS 'key', `country_name` AS value 
FROM countries;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT `id` AS `key`, `country_name` AS value 
FROM countries;
```

Comment: A point to note - use backticks in cases only when you are using a reserved word as a name. Otherwise, there is no good reason to wrap names in backticks, given that this is not ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`key` is mysql keyword  so compiler suppose as mysql keyword, you should warp by apostrophe(`) to column name

```
SELECT `id` AS `key`, `country_name` AS value 
FROM countries
```