# Whats wrong with this query? Using ands

Tags: php, mysql

I've got no errors, nothing, but for some reason my page is blank, thanks to this:

```
$userBusca = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM account.login_admin WHERE login='".$login."' AND password='".$password."' AND key='".$key_load."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

The login and password are froma  form, and the key_load is a string from a text file.

Is there anythin wrong with this?

EDIT: everything works without the key='".$key_load."'

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: I'm not, the password is already hashed

Comment: Put the query in Db phpmyadmin. You will get to know error!

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='".$key_load."'' at line 1 ; how do I solve that?

Comment: I didn't know it was a keyword, not everyone has your knowledge, stop being so salty

Comment: In addition: you have mixed MySQL API's `mysqli_` and `mysql_` (in your `die` statement) which will not work.

Comment: *"I'm not, the password is already hashed"* - I did not know that, which is why I added that to my answer, just in case ;-) @JoaoPaulo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AND key`

- `key` is a MySQL reserved word.
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html

wrap it in ticks

```
AND `key`
```

Or rename it to something else, like `the_key`, but don't try `keys` because that too is a MySQL reserved word.

You're also mixing APIs with `mysql_error()` which should be `mysqli_error($conn)`

- Those different MySQL APIs/functions do not intermix with each other.

---

Also, am hoping you are storing a safe hash.

If not:

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Can he give Alias like `column name AS key` ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com No they cannot. See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/27309977/

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Addendum to above... well, yes they can, but they would still need to wrap the reserved word in ticks `\``.